# Is there an infrastructure similar and/or with the same functionality as the Java Annotation Processing Tool (APT) in the Dart Language?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, dart, apt

The Java APT includes a set of reflective APIs and supporting infrastructure to process program annotations, and I want to know if there is something similar in Dart.

Comment: @JasonC I don't think this is a duplicate. The referenced question is about runtime access and I think APT is about build time access to annotations.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I guess it does read that way; I've removed the vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something similar with the [analyzer package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/analyzer). This package allows you to get the [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) or *Resolved AST* (with types) from sources and navigate inside it.

So yes, you can process source codes like with [apt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/apt/).

Answer (score 2):

I have never uses Java APT and did just a very brief Google search
but of what I understand this is already used in several Dart packages.
There are source mirrors, you can reflect on Dart source code without actually running it.
This is usually used in transformers which are executed during the build process.
You can add custom transformers in the the `pubspec.yaml` configuration file.

This package may be worth a look: http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/smoke
source repository: https://github.com/dart-lang/bleeding_edge/tree/master/dart/pkg/smoke

Comment: You said: _"I have never uses Java APT and did just a very brief Google search but of what I understand this is used in several Dart packages yet."_  Can you clarify this? Do you mean "this is used" or "this _isn't_ used"?

Comment: I mean that what I think APT is, could be totally wrong. I read just a few sentences from search results I found. If my understanding is not totally wrong than this might be similar than what several Dart packages are using. Like Polymer that uses the `smoke` library to convert code that uses reflection for reading/monitoring fields annotated with `@published` or `@observable` to code that doesn't use reflection.